# Passing single model to modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass specific model from list to a modal linked by a button.

```
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    FirstName
                </th>
            </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
           <tr>
             <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
             </td>
             <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
             </td>
             <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
                  data-target="#detailsModal">
                    Details
                </button>
            </td>
          }
        </table>
```

In my model, I have a `@Html.RenderPartial` method to pass the data and further process it to display in the format I wanted to display. Is there any way I can access the item model from the above without using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create details modal for all items with modal id that is the id of model item like that:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
                  data-target="#@item.Id">
                    Details
                </button>
```

and the modal dialog like that:

```
    <div class="modal" id="@item.Id">
<!--code to render the details here-->
    </div>
```